# read by white space

Tags: python, readfile

I have a .txt file with the following single line

```
(1,65,b) (2,50,r) (3,80,b) (4,10,b) (5,60,b) (6,70,r) (8,5,r) (11,62,r)
```

where the first element of the tuple is the position, second is value and the third one is color. For example for the first tuple: position = 1, value = 65 and color is b.

**How can I read this file in a way that I can create list of positions, values, and colors.**

Comment: What do you want the output to look like given your example here?

Comment: Could you share what code have you tried so far?

Comment: for position list of following variables. [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11]  Same for the value and color as well. So list of positions, values and colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (explanation in code comment):

```
file = "(1,65,b) (2,50,r) (3,80,b) (4,10,b) (5,60,b) (6,70,r) (8,5,r) (11,62,r)"

positions=[]
values=[]
colors=[]
# assuming that the values are stored in one line in the file, loop through text in file splitting text by space
for item in file.split(" "):
    # split the text in between brackets [text betwen 1 to -1 >[1:-1] by comma
    # append each item to corosponding list
    positions.append(item[1:-1].split(",")[0])
    values.append(item[1:-1].split(",")[1])
    colors.append(item[1:-1].split(",")[2])

print(positions, values, colors)
```

One line solution:

```
file = "(1,65,b) (2,50,r) (3,80,b) (4,10,b) (5,60,b) (6,70,r) (8,5,r) (11,62,r)"
p,c,v = [list(map(lambda x:x[1:-1].split(",")[i], file.split(" ") )) for i in range(3)]
print (p,c,v)
```

Comment: Just a word of caution, this approach would require to load the whole file in a variable for it to work.

Comment: @EcemŞimşek You're welcome. Added a one line solution for a shorter code

Comment: @SwetankPoddar What would be a better approach to this?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar I don't think this will be a problem as OP said the entire file contains a single line

Comment: @ThaerA, Ah okay, if it's a single line then there's no scalability issue. However, a more robust approach would be to either create a parser which reads character by character and constructs the tuple or the input file could be changed to have only one tuple every line and then use ```readline```.

Answer (score 1):

You can you [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) for searching the string.

```
import re

string = open ('text.txt').read()

position = list(map(int,re.findall(f'\(([0-9]+)',string)))
value = list(map(int,re.findall(f',([0-9]+)',string)))
color = list(re.findall(f'([a-z])\)',string))
print(position,value,color)

#output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11] [65, 50, 80, 10, 60, 70, 5, 62] ['b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution using replace .

```
import os
import time
import sys

output  = "(1,65,b) (2,50,r) (3,80,b) (4,10,b) (5,60,b) (6,70,r) (8,5,r) (11,62,r)"

a = ((((output.replace("(",'')).replace(")",'')).replace(' ',',')).split(','))

e = a[0::3]
f = a[1::3]
g = a[2::3]

print(e,f,g)

Output:
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '11'] ['65', '50', '80', '10', '60', '70', '5', '62'] ['b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r']
```